# Is polymorphism the best way to achieve this? (regarding function calls in derived classes)

Tags: c++, class, object, c++11, polymorphism

I have a program that has four classes:

- Vehicle (Base)
- Automobile (Derived from Vehicle)
- Car (Derived from Automobile)
- Truck (Derived from Automobile)

At run-time, the user generates a Automobile object which is either a "Car" or "Truck" using a factory function:

```
Automobile *Automobile::make_automobile(std::string choice) {
    if (choice == "car")
        return new Car;
    else if (choice == "truck")
        return new Truck;
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

Now, the "Car" class has three unique setters (and three matching getters):

- Set_NumDoors()
- Set_SeatMaterial()
- Set_Shape()

The "Truck" class has one unique setter (and a matching getter):

- Set_CargoWeight()

At first, these functions were only implemented in their own classes, but I could not call them at run-time since the object created was an "Automobile" object. I have solved this issue using virtual functions with local overrides. So now, the "Automobile" class all four functions (in virtual form), which by default do nothing. However, when called on an object, the local override performs the correct functionality. Below is an example, and it all works.

Definition in Automobile class

```
std::string defaultStatement = "Function call is invalid on current object";
    virtual int set_seatMaterial(std::string choice){
        std::cout << defaultStatement << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

Override in Car class

```
    int set_seatMaterial(std::string choice) override { // override virtual base
        if (choice == "leather" || choice == "cloth"){
            seatMaterial = choice;
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

I then use function pointers in main() to point to the required function as appropriate:

```
if (user_choice == "seat"){
            std::function<int(Automobile*, std::string)> choiceFunction = &Automobile::set_seatMaterial;
            choiceFunction(userVehicle, seatMaterial);
}
```

The only question I have is - is this the best way of achieving this functionality? It works but now I have declarations of every single function in the "Automobile" class, which already has its own getters/setters. It seems like duplication in a sense, although I understand the concept of polymorphism and its usefulness.

Or is there a better way to call a derived class function from a base class object?

Comment: The `Automobile::set_seatMaterial` function should probably be abstract instead of implemented. I.e. `virtual int set_seatMaterial(std::string choice) = 0;`

Comment: And what is the design reason for something like `choiceFunction`? What is wrong with just plain `userVehicle->set_seatMaterial(seatMaterial)`?

Comment: It is for run-time operation. I do not know which property of the vehicle they want to set, so the pointer grabs the function they choose and then calls it.

Comment: "Is X the best way to achieve Y?" IMHO This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers. Until then, I vote close.

Comment: How should I update it to reflect that? Is it not a valid question to ask advice regarding best practices?

Comment: Regarding `choiceFunction`, you don't really use it as a generic function to be called from somewhere else, you call it *directly* if `user_choice == "seat"`. So why not `if (user_choice == "seat") { userVehicle->set_seatMaterial(seatMaterial); }`?

Comment: That's a good point, the program isn't finished yet as I was just testing the polymorphism. I am going to create a generic function that returns the specific function pointer based on their choice, to avoid repeating the code for each property they want to set. 

That was next on my list, but first I wanted advice on whether the overall method was an advisable one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have solved this issue using virtual functions with local overrides. So now, the "Automobile" class all four functions (in virtual form), which by default do nothing. However, when called on an object, the local override performs the correct functionality. Below is an example, and it all works.

That makes it necessary for the implentor of `Automobile` to know all the methods that all the classes that inherits from it provides which makes it hard to maintain.

Another option is to `dynamic_cast` in the situations where you need to know what type of `Automobile` you're dealing with.

C++11 example:

```
Automobile* unknown = ...;

if(auto car = dynamic_cast<Car*>(unknown)) {
    // call car-specific methods
    car->Set_NumDoors(4);

} else if(auto truck = dynamic_cast<Truck*>(unknown)) {
    // call truck-specific methods
    truck->Set_CargoWeight(1000);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8oEnh9)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, and this is precisely the issue I want to avoid. But how can I call the car-specific methods on the "Automobile" object as you advise? It is not in the list of available methods since it is not a car object.

Comment: @Cato If you do `Automobile* unknown = new Car;` you can call `car->Set_NumDoors(...);` in the block where `car` is not `nullptr` above. - I added that to the answer.

Comment: Yes I see, but the issue is I don't know which Automobile they will choose. It is always an Automobile but it only becomes a Car object at run-time IF they choose a Car. So I cannot call the methods in advance (which is why I used virtual and overrides as above).

Comment: @Cato Yes, and this code deals with this in runtime. The `dynamic_cast` will try to get a `Car*` from the `Automobile*` and if it works, the user choose a `Car`.

Comment: Ooooh, sorry! I misread your post, I was trying to call the method on "Unknown" but you meant call it on the "car" object. My apologies! Will this work in C++11 though? My IDE says this is limited to C++17 and newer.

Comment: @Cato Yes, that's correct. It'll work in C++11 too - it's only the init-statement in the `if` that is C++17 specific. I've updated the answer to work in C++11.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, it states "'if' initialization statements are a C++17 extension" and therefore returns an error when running the code.

Comment: @Cato I've updated the Demo too to work in C++11.

Comment: Ted.. thank you! Your suggestion worked perfectly. Your solution seems so much more ideal than the 'polymorphic style' alternative. Is there any downside to your approach?

Comment: @Cato You're welcome. It has some runtime cost but I don't see that cost being less if calling "empty" methods in classes that are not supposed to have them implemented, so I can't really see any real downside with it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Whilst refactoring the code I discovered something - the Automobile class still needs at least one virtual function declared within it. If this is not done, dynamic_cast will throw an error "Automobile is not polymorphic". It's not really an issue but I thought it was intriguing. Unless there is a way to overcome this?

Comment: The common base class should have a `virtual` destructor like I made in the demo. In your case `virtual ~Vehicle() = default;` - otherwise you'd risk all sorts of problems.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually exactly one problem: Undefined behavior when you destroy a derived object through a `Vehicle` pointer, which is typically done in polymorphic designs where objects are created in factories, stored as base class pointer (-collections) and destroyed through those.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica True, I can't edit the comment, but I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Your question indeed concerns a principal design problem. Generally spoken, polymorphism is most adequate if the objects can usually be treated identically. The exact type of the object then needs to be known only in a few specific situations. In other words, there is a significant common subset of behavior that is common to all cars, in your example, and most of the times we don't even want to know which sort of car we have here. If you find yourself programming Ted's if-else chains over and over again it may be an indication that the vehicles are different enough to warrant separate processing. If you find that it is so, you would for example not have a vector of pointers to cars but instead separate vectors of trucks and automobiles and semis and what not, which are processed separately.

But let's assume that polymorphism is a valid approach here because there is only a limited number of situations where each type of car needs special treatment: When you buy a car, when you repair one, when you dispose of one. For example, an automobile buyer may want to choose the seat material while the company buying a truck doesn't have that choice. There are, obviously, many more things that may be different int the respective car "setup".

The solution here is to specify an abstract car base class method for each of the respective situations.  For example, each car would have a  "setup" routine which interacts with the user and obtains the required subtype-specific information. So instead of the if-else chain you rely on polymorphism again to do the right thing for you. This works if you can fit all the different behaviors into a uniform abstract pattern which you describe by abstract methods in the base class. The downside is that the objects may need information about their environs (an iostream, a graphics context, database access, whatever) which has nothing really to do with their actual function. We would principally like to keep these things separate from the cars for the sake of weak component coupling. So here, too, this approach works best if the objects are similar enough that they need a similar set of information which can be passed to the common method (instead of being known to the respective car object).

As a conclusion, here is a general rule of thumb: While Ted's answer is not wrong one should always be suspicious of dynamic casts and if-else chains; they are often a sign of lacking abstraction.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the detailed explanation. I am new to C++ so some of what you said went over my head, but I will reflect on it more as I continue building more complex programmes. I am keen to pick up best practices as early as possible so thanks very much for your advice.